# GeolocationException on Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am attempting to add Maps to my Xamarin forms application. When I open the app, it errors with the following:

> Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.GeolocationException has been thrown
>
> A geolocation error occurred: Unauthorized

The first time, a popup appears when I run the app to ask if I can access location, and I accepted. The popup no longer appears when I run the app, it just errors. The ItemsPage is the first screen I am directed, where the app crashes. I have included my .plist file. I was following [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/) guide from Xamarin.

**Main.cs (iOS)**

```
public class Application
{
    // This is the main entry point of the application.
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // if you want to use a different Application Delegate class from "AppDelegate"
        // you can specify it here.
        UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate"); // error thrown here
    }
}
```

**ItemsPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
    x:Class="Divco.ItemsPage" 
    Title="{Binding Title}" 
    x:Name="BrowseItemsPage">
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Logout" Command="{Binding LogoutCommand}"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <!--<maps:Map WidthRequest="320" HeightRequest="300"
            x:Name="MyMap"
            IsShowingUser="false"
            MapType="Street"/>-->
        <ListView x:Name="ItemsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasUnevenRows="true" RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Padding="10">
                            <Label Text="{Binding id}" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" FontSize="16" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding description}" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}" FontSize="13" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**AppDelegate.cs**

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init();

        LoadApplication(new App());



        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
}
```

**Info.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>{Hidden}</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>{Hidden}</string>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>{Hidden}</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
<true/>
<key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
<string>8.0</string>
<key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
<array>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <integer>2</integer>
</array>
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>LaunchScreen</string>
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>armv7</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
<string>Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset</string>
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>MKDirectionsRequest</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.apple.maps.directionsrequest</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>MKDirectionsApplicationSupportedModes</key>
<array>
    <string>MKDirectionsModeCar</string>
</array>
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>location</string>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access always to location.</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access location when open.</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Eventually, I would like to comment out the maps portions in the xaml to show the current location of the user.

Comment: Have you added Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(); in the AppDelegate?

Comment: @SteveChadbourne yes. I'll add it to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription` is also needed in `info.plist`  after `iOS 11` for requesting always Authorization.

Detail Refer to [Requesting Always Authorization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/choosing_the_authorization_level_for_location_services/requesting_always_authorization)